# What factors influence IE in determining whether or not to send a cross-domain cookie?

Tags: iis, cookies, cross-domain

Working on troubleshooting an interface consumed by 3rd parties.  The quick overview:

- 3rd party sends the user out our site `example.com/login` to let the user authenticate with us
- After signin we redirect the user back to `thirdparty.com`
- `thirdparty.com` consumes a dynamic JS file on our site used to return information about the logged in user `example.com/dynamicJs.js`

  - Since this request is made against `example.com` it *should* include the cookies dropped during login (they are required for it to serve its purpose)
  - **for IE, they are no longer being included in the request**

In researching:

- the cookies themselves don't appear to have changed, and manually navigating IE to the URL of `dynamicJS.js` results in the necessary cookies being transmitted.
- `example.com` has P3P policies in place and is not generating any visible warnings/errors with IE
- other browsers include the cookies

So, what other variables could be influencing IE and resulting in it omitting the `example.com` cookies when loading `example.com/dynamicJS.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research we identified the root of the issue was within IIS's Custom HTTP Response Headers.

Previously we had configured the site to return a `P3P` header, but in diagnosing this issue we found that somehow the header was now being returned as `3P`.  Returning the key to `P3P` resolved out issue.

In researching the actual cause of this change we found that the bad header originated in the `web.config`, within the `<httpProtocol><customHeaders>` element -- however it appeared to have been placed there some time ago and remained dormant until the AppPool was stopped/restarted for maintenance.